# How to reactivate Windows Error Reporting for my application (cpp)? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-error-reporting

## TLDR

When one of my applications executes `_CrtDbgBreak()` it just writes a .dmp file and exits. On any other application `_CrtDbgBreak()` causes the *app.exe has stopped working* -dialog where I can chose to break into my debugger (VS 2013).

This is my desired behavior.

### Background

A few weeks ago I experimented with Windows Error Reporting to find out if/how the WER Dialog could be suppressed. Apparently I succeeded for my application and unfortunately I haven't found the way how to undo this.

In the meantime I have had to deal with a number of other things so that I no longer remember which steps I exactly took at the time. (Should have taken notes, I know.) Since it works for other applications, I am guessing a setting specific to my app needs to be reset.

I turned to the usual suspects on my machine but so far I haven't found anything:

- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
- Policy Editor: Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Error Reporting
- Policy Editor: User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Error Reporting
- WER Service is running

I have even removed all occurrences of my executable's name from my entire registry but this hasn't made any difference. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is your app/exe is added to the WER's exclusion list. See 'ExcludedApplications' at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/wer-settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Werapi/nf-werapi-weraddexcludedapplication

Check registry at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ExcludedApplications

If your app/exe name is found there, remove it.

Comment: Also, do share the OS version your are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I already checked, neither key has an ExcludedApplications subkey.

Comment: You have to either call the api function, or add the key manually. That's how the registry works, parent keys or values that do not exist simply assume the default behaviour, and reduces the registry hive size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd set the process error mode, like so

```
SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
```

(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode)

[yes - the question is dated, but it's not marked as answered, and this alternative solution may help future readers]